# ServletException because of MessageDispatcherServlet.properties file not found

Tags: java, spring, maven, weblogic, war

I am trying to acccess a webservice using weblogic. 
I have deployed the .war file but I am getting following exception whenever I try to access the service.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not load 'class path resource [org/springframework/ws/transport/http/MessageDispatcherServlet.properties]': class path resource [org/springframework/ws/transport/http/MessageDispatcherServlet.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist
            at org.springframework.ws.support.DefaultStrategiesHelper.<init>(DefaultStrategiesHelper.java:77)
            at org.springframework.ws.transport.http.MessageDispatcherServlet.<init>(MessageDispatcherServlet.java:133)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
            Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Following Spring jars are present in the WEB-INF/lib folder

---

```
spring-aop-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-asm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-aspects-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-beans-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-support-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-expression-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-jms-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-modules-validation-0.8a.jar
spring-orm-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-oxm-1.5.7.jar
spring-oxm-tiger-1.5.7.jar
spring-security-core-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-security-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-web-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-webmvc-3.0.2.RELEASE.jar
spring-ws-core-1.5.9.jar
spring-xml-1.5.7.jar
```

---

What am I missing here?

Thanks

Comment: Start by opening the `spring-ws-core` with a zip manager and checking if the file is actually there.

Comment: Ah. Cleaning the Weblogic cache got this resolved. Closing this now